# Windows Universal App _TemporaryKey.pfx Does Not Exist Import/Open Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp-xaml

I'm an Absolute beginner in using visual studio 2015 and has a little background in `C#` and `XAML`. I'm following a series of tutorial in how to make windows apps in YouTube. And from the video they shared a repo/projects from the video.

The problem was that, when I open it, add the solution. And Build the project I get many errors, due to `ProjectName_TemporaryKey.pfx` .

[image: Img]

Here's the [Link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLi2hbezQRVS0cPMeW3uDlUHnO_rPvJCV9) of the video that I was following, and the github account [link](https://github.com/Windows-Readiness/AbsoluteBeginnersWin10) in case you want to view it yourself.

**How to I solve this problem? **

I really need your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem, with the help of this [link].[1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c33d7f75-6893-4793-a407-3aa3d49c098c/temporarykeypfx?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

First go to `Project` and clicked the `project properties`
[image: sample]

Second - go to `Signing` and check the `Sign the Assembly` 
[image: sample2]

Lastly - save the project and `Build or ReBuild` the Solution